# How to update status of an uncleared eCheck transaction in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

My Application fetches transaction using the PayPal API, for a day or a particular time period. The Next time it fetches from the last fetched time to the current time and not the whole data.

So, The Problem I am facing is on a particular day I get a transaction that says 'eCheck Payment received' with status as 'Pending'. But as you know eCheck takes some time to be cleared in a real Transaction in PayPal, So what happens is after some days when the eCheck is Cleared I don't receive a Transaction that says that eCheck is Cleared.

How am I suppose to find it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The TransactionSearch call does not return cleared eCheque transactions (it's the only type of transaction that's missing). I have been in touch with PayPal directly about just this problem, and after several months they came back with: "this is expected behaviour", and so they don't see it as a problem.

When you login to your PayPal account, and when you do a CSV download, the cleared transaction shows (on the date and time it cleared), but when using the API it doesn't, they just update the original transaction.

What we've ended up doing is using the API TransactionSearch call for everything else, and then use the GetTransactionDetails call on any transactions that are 'pending' (status) to check if it changes to 'completed'.

As far as I know, you can't download any cleared eCheque transactions using the API, only the original transaction that gets changed to 'completed', even though there are two transactions with unique transaction id's.